# how do I restart the live google app engine server?

Tags: google-app-engine

I keep getting 'That user can undo the transaction with "appcfg rollback"' error, so I want to know, how can I just restart the server, instead of trying to deploy?

**Step 1:**

appcfg.py rollback .

**output:**

06:36 PM Application: blah-app-dev-2
06:36 PM Host: appengine.google.com
06:36 PM Rolling back the update.

**Step 2:** 
appcfg.py update workers/workers.yaml

**output:**

06:37 PM Host: appengine.google.com
06:37 PM Application: blah-app-dev-2; module: workers; version: v1
06:37 PM 
Starting update of app: blah-app-dev-2, module: workers, version: v1
06:37 PM Getting current resource limits.
06:37 PM Scanning files on local disk.
Error 409: --- begin server output ---
Another transaction by user jill is already in progress for app: s~blah-app-dev-2, version: v1. That user can undo the transaction with "appcfg rollback".
--- end server output ---

Now what?

Answer (score 1):

You can shut down all instances in your developer console, but it will not solve your problem. You have to execute the rollback command.

Comment: I deleted the entire module... then I redeployed.. I still got the same error.. now what?

Comment: Specify module that you are rolling back.